# Django: one of pages is not opening

Tags: python, django

I have created two pages locally for Django site:

1. http://127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio/
2. http://127.0.0.1:8080/about_me/

when I want to open "http://127.0.0.1:8080/about_me/" always opens this one "http://127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio/". Do you know reason for this?

project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
     path('portfolio/', include('blog.urls')),
     path('about_me/', include('blog.urls')),
    ]
```

app urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('about_me/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='about_me'),
    path('portfolio/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='portfolio'),
   
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),


    ]
# to jest dla wysiwyg
  # add condition in django urls file

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Your both 'about_me' and 'portfolio' url pointing to same views.Change it to corresponding views. path('about_me/', views.Aboutme.as_view(), name='about_me'),
path('portfolio/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='portfolio'),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `urls.py` both `about_me` and `portfolio` points to the same function.

```
path('about_me/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='about_me'),
path('portfolio/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='portfolio'),
```

Both `urls` points to your `Portfolio` view.
So change `views` function name accordingly in your `urls.py`.

```
path('about_me/', views.YourAboutMeView.as_view(), name='about_me'), #<---- change this view name accordingly
path('portfolio/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='portfolio'),
```

Answer (score 1):

May be beacuse when have in app urls.py

```
 path('about_me/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='about_me'),
 path('portfolio/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='portfolio'),
```

you have used

```
views.Portfolio
```

for both about_me and portfolio

Comment: thanks for this, after correction it is working  now :)

Comment: What' the error??

Comment: no error, I updated as you mentioned and is working now

Comment: use this link to know how you can do it

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow